# Sefer about Tzniyus in loshon Hakodesh

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, tznius-modesty

I am looking for recommendations for a sefer in Loshon Hakodesh about the laws of tznius (modesty).

If anyone knows of any comprehensive sefer, please respond!

[I already know about Rabbi Falk’s "Oz Vhdor Levusha"].

Comment: Although not seeking English works, once you've mentioned R. Falk's work (which is in English), it is worth mentioning R. Yehuda Henkin's [Understanding Tzniut](http://www.urimpublications.com/understanding-tzniut-modern-controversies-in-the-jewish-community.html) which is a work in critique/response.

Comment: Thank you @Deuteronomy he has both in English and in Hebrew. I will Bezh look at this book

Comment: No problem, I hope it helps you in your understanding of the area :)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on who it is for.

For men - HaRav Nissim Karelitz zt"l has a popular series entitled [Chut Shani](https://www.shopeichlers.com/products/chut-shani-tznius/39895) one of which is on tznius.

For women and kallos, you might want to consider the two volume set entitled [Yofi shel tznius](https://www.feldheim.com/yofi-shel-tznius-2-vol-hebrew-only-1). The blurb there reads:

> For women and Kallahs, filled with theoretical ideas along with practical applications. Based on Chazal and Gedolim, the author presents the subject of Tznius, modesty, in an easy-to-read style, providing guidance for many every day situations. It has the approval of numerous Rabbinic authorities.

Between spouses:
There is [Shaarei Tznius](https://www.shopeichlers.com/products/shaarei-tznius/54123). The inside page reads:

> הלכות צניעות הנוהגים בין איש לאשתו ע"פ ש"ע או"ח סימן ר"מ ושו"ע אה"ע סימנים כ"ג וכ"ה עם ביאורים והוספות ונוסף קיצור הלכות טהרה

Comment: Thank you, I started looking at these today!

Comment: No problem - I hope they help with what you are looking for. Hatzlocho!